# Understanding routes + module/class names in Ruby on Rails 6 [and what a module is in this context]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, module, routes

If I have a route that is looking up a controller action in a specific location, e.g.:

```
things_path     GET /things     some/things#index
```

I can satisfy this path with either of the following:

```
# app/controllers/some/things_controller.rb
class Some::ThingsController
  def index
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

```
# app/controllers/some/things_controller.rb
module Some
  class ThingsController
    def index
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```

But **not**:

```
# app/controllers/some/things_controller.rb
class ThingsController
  def index
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

And I don't understand why, or what it means about the term `module`...

In my head the route is wanting to find a `things_controller.rb` in the `some` directory (on an autoloaded path, [I have specified `app/controllers`]).

Why does rails need the contents of my file to specify/match with the location?

If `module Some` is having the same effect as `Some::`, what does that mean a module is/is doing here? Is it **really** a module... or is it a namespace?!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby on Rails uses a constant autoloader named [Zeitwerk](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk). This autoloader loads constants, which is the reason you never have to [`require`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) your own project files (in `app/`).

[This autoloading system comes with some file structure constraints/pre-requisites.](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#file-structure) For example the constant `Admin::UsersController` must be defined in `admin/users_controller.rb` file in any of the `app/*` directories.

On `Admin::UsersController` lookup, the autoloader will first search for `admin.rb`. If this file is not found then `Admin` is assumed to be a namespace and [the autoloader will create the `Admin` module dynamically](https://github.com/fxn/zeitwerk#implicit-namespaces). After loading `Admin` the autoloader then looks for `admin/users_controller.rb`.

You can define `ThingsController` in the `app/controllers/some/things_controller.rb` file, but you'll have to mark `app/controllers/some/` as [autoload paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths), which is probably not what you want. The arguably better option is to move the file to `app/controllers/things_controller.rb` instead.

For a full explanation about the autoloader I suggest reading the [Ruby on Rails - Autoloading and Reloading Constants (Zeitwerk Mode)](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) guide.

---

The difference between:

```
module Admin
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
  end
end
```

And:

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
end
```

Is the constant lookup context.

In the first scenario if you where to use a constant within the `UsersController`. Ruby looks for the constant in the following manner:

- `Admin::UsersController::MY_CONSTANT`
- if above not found: `Admin::MY_CONSTANT`
- if above not found: `::MY_CONSTANT` (root constant)
- if above not found: `NameError (uninitialized constant ...)`

**The second scenario is similar but skips the `Admin::MY_CONSTANT` step**, because you don't open up the `Admin` module.

Note that anything starting with a capital letter is considered a constant, this can be a constant value like above (often full caps, but not required), but classes and modules are also constants (often camel cased).

For more info about constant lookup checkout [Everything you ever wanted to know about constant lookup in Ruby](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, it really helped :)

Comment: when you say "`On Admin::UsersController` lookup, the autoloader will first search for `admin.rb`", do you mean that it is looking in `admin.rb` for a constant `UsersController`? So if it found one there, it would stop looking for anything else? (e.g. never find `users_controller.rb`). And if you had `admin.rb`, but no `UsersController` defined, it would keep looking/would still create the `Admin` namespace automatically?

Comment: @JoshuaESummers No. If you access `Admin::UsersController` you are essentially requesting 2 constants. First You requests `Admin`, then you request `UsersController` within the `Admin` namespace. The autoloader expects `admin.rb` to load the `Admin` module or class. Without the `Admin` constant loaded you cannot access anything within that namespace. After loading `Admin` it looks for `admin/users_controller.rb` to load the namespaced `UsersController`. The autoloader does not expect `users.rb` to define `UsersController`.

Comment: Also when you say "On Admin::UsersController lookup", what does that mean? As in when is "lookup" triggered? Would it be when someone goes to that route for example?

Comment: re your first answer... so if it found `admin.rb` which defined the module/class... it does not matter if `UserController` is not defined within the file, it just needs to generate the namespace...?

Comment: @JoshuaESummers Yes, it just needs to generate the namespace. If `Admin` is only used as namespace then you don't even need the `admin.rb` file. It will be created by the autoloader. However, if you want some special constants within your `Admin` namespace you could place them in `admin.rb` (where you define the module/class).

Comment: A lookup is triggered when you refer to a constant. For controllers this is done by the framework. Rails will create an instance of your controller as soon as a network request is routed to your controller. A more obvious example is within the controller you probably refer to your models. For example the `PostsController` might have the following in its `create` action. `Post.new(post_params)` If the `Post` constant is not loaded, the autoloader will try to find it.